# jquery post() appending unwanted data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I'm testing the post() method of jQuery but I have a problem. I create 2 inputs in my html:

```
<label>box 1:</label><input type="text" name="box1" id="box1" autocomplete="off" size="20"/>
<label>box 2:</label><input type="text" name="box2" id="box2" autocomplete="off" size="20"/>
```

My function test()

```
function test(){
    var box1v = $('#box1').val();
    var box2v = $('#box2').val();
    $.post("test.php",{'box1':box1v,'box2':box2v},function(data){
        alert(data)
    });
}
```

and in my test.php I only do:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

the alert gives me

```
Array ( [box1]=>'value1',[box2]=>'value2')0
```

is the 0 at the end that is causing me problems because when I use
`$_POST[box1]` it gives me `value10`
the same with `$_POST[box2]` who gives me `value20`

I don't know where this `0` is appending. Does anybody can explain me how to avoid this unwanted data please?

Comment: look in the php , it's coming from there. Create a new file `test2.php` with nothing in it but `<?php print_r($_POST);` and I bet it comes back clean

Comment: did you try to `exit;` or `die();` after you print?

Comment: but the php is only doing a echo of the variables

Comment: @Romili Paredes When doing `print_r`, you shouldn't get any data outside the closing-parenthesis (`$_POST` is an array, nothing more). It's impossible that you only echo those variables in that file... If you're sure, then send us the entire `test2.php` file, to show us.